# Android toolbar doesn't display icons and titles

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I am using toolbar to make a customized action bar. I have a class called BaseActivity which I inherit in all other activity. It merges the toolbar to actionbar. But the thing is I ma not getting the toolbar icons and titles visible.

Here's my BaseActivity:

```
package com.meroanswer.classes;

import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.meroanswer.R;

public abstract class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResource());
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Window window = getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutResource();

    protected void setActionBarIcon(int iconRes) {
        try{
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(iconRes);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.d("Roshan", "Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my derived page code

```
package com.meroanswer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.meroanswer.DrawerAdapter;
import com.meroanswer.MainActivity;
import com.meroanswer.R;
import com.meroanswer.SlidingTabLayout;
import com.meroanswer.ViewPagerAdapter;
import com.meroanswer.classes.BaseActivity;
import com.meroanswer.classes.Helper;
import com.meroanswer.connection.AsyncPut;
import com.meroanswer.connection.Connection;
import com.meroanswer.database.model.Stream;
import com.meroanswer.database.model.User;

import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class SettingsPage extends BaseActivity {
    public WebView webview;
    Helper helper;
    Context context;
    private String temp_str;


    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    DrawerLayout Drawer;

    String TITLES[] = {
            "Coupons",
            "Upgrade to Premium",
            "Rate us",
            "Share App",
            "Settings",
            "About",
            "Log out"
    };

    int ICONS[] = {
            R.drawable.coupon,
            R.drawable.premium,
            R.drawable.star,
            R.drawable.share,
            R.drawable.settings,
            R.drawable.about,
            R.drawable.logout
    };


    String NAME = "A B";
    String EMAIL = "a@b.com";
    int PROFILE = R.drawable.profile;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_page);

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_ab_drawer);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");


        helper = new Helper(context);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.dashboard_webview);
        WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
        settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

        int android_version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (android_version >= 11) {
            webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new SettingsProvider(this, webview),
                "Android");
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ma_html/setup.html");

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        //drawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, Gravity.START);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

        mAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
        // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
        // and header view profile picture
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_settings_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.activity_settings_page;
    }

    }
}
```

and here's my layout resource file for the activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </WebView>

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<!--<ListView
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/windowBackgroundColor"/>-->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

menu file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.meroanswer.SettingsPage">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: post your menu file..

Comment: @Keshav1234 added it ..please check.

Comment: where are your icons which you need in toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following and check whether you can see changes:

Change the menu.xml as shown below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.meroanswer.SettingsPage">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always" /> // This line has been changed from never to always
</menu>
```

In your onOptionsItemSelected method add the following part:

```
int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Settings button has been selected", Toast.Length_Long).show();
            return true;
        }
```

After these run the application and click on the settings text ion tool bar you will see a toast message.

Hope it helps.